# Object shifts about after changing XYZ Euler to Quaternion (WXYZ)

Tags: animation, quaternion

I have a problem when I change the rotation type of my object (3D View > Properties region (N) > Transform panel > Rotation) from XYZ Euler to Quaternion (WXYZ) to avoid a gimbal lock problem with a collada export.

I find that after the change, while the bone animation still plays perfectly, the object now seems to shift around slightly. I believe it has something to do with the root position or the in place motion as child bones seem to behave perfectly.

Here is a [video of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOYLt_7fCZw). The initial import using euler is on the left and the right side shows the change to quaternions. Note how the feet are very grounded on the left but on the right they drift about and leave the ground.

Any suggestions on how to fix the issue would be greatly appreciated as I think I'm pretty close to getting it working!